# Не могу нарисовать прямоугольник в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

Использую Canvas() для рисования фигур. Подскажите, почему не отрисовывается прямоугольник.

```
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(150, 150, 175, 175, fill = 'black'
root.mainloop()
```

*Пробовал на repl.it, pydroid3*, результат-пустое окно.

Comment: Потому что canvas забыли в окне разместить (с помощью pack, grid или place)

Comment: Пробую `rect.place(150, 150)` итог: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'place'

Comment: Не rect, а canvas. Вы создали холст (Canvas), нарисовали на нем прямоугольник, но в окне холст не разместили.

Comment: `pack()` работает, `place()`-нет

Comment: Все три варианта работают.

Comment: `TypeError: place_configure() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: Внимательно посмотрите примеры с place, потом сравните с тем, как вы делаете.

Comment: При `place()` выдает ошибку.

Comment: Хотя я дал 2 аргумента/_\

Comment: Смотрите, первая ссылка в поисковике по запросу "tkinter place": https://younglinux.info/tkinter/place Там в примере `.place(x=75, y=20)`, но вы просто пишете типа `.place(75, 20)`, в этом случае выдает ошибку как вы написали в комментарии. Поэтому я и написал выше: внимательно посмотрите примеры с place, потом сравните с тем, как вы делаете

Comment: Впрочем, и с `pack()` сойдёт. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(150, 150, 175, 175, fill = 'black')
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]